# SQL Sorting with 3 Joined Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these three tables

```
people
============
id, name
```

,

```
surveys
============
id, org_id
```

and

```
answer_sheets
============
id, person_id, survey_id, answer, date_answered
```

- `person_id` and `survey_id` are foreign keys from `people.id` and `surveys.id`

Now, what I wanted to do is to sort `people` in such in order basing it on the latest `answer_sheets.date_answered` (we can derive that one `surveys` AND `people` row can have many `answer_sheets`) given the `surveys.org_id`

Say for example we have the tables

```
people  
============
id  name  
1   Person1  
2   Person2  
3   Person3  
4   Person4  
5   Person5  

surveys
============
id  org_id  
1   1  
2   1
3   2
4   2


answer_sheets  
=============
id  person_id   survey_id   answer  date_answered  
1   1           1           string  JUN 13  
2   2           1           string  JUN 15  
3   3           2           string  JUN 17  
4   2           2           string  JUN 18  
5   1           2           string  JUN 19  
6   3           3           string  JUN 20  
7   2           3           string  JUN 25  
8   4           3           string  JUN 27  
9   4           4           string  JUN 27
```

and I wanted to order `people` in `ASC` order based on a `people` row's latest `answer_sheets.date_answered` in surveys having `org_id` = 1

the output would be

```
=============
id  name      last_date_answered
4   Person4   NIL
5   Person5   NIL
3   Person3   JUN 17
2   Person2   JUN 18
1   Person1   JUN 19
```

You can observe that `people` with `id`s 4 and 5 does not have an `answer_sheet` in `surveys` with `org_id` = 1 and yet they should be included in the list.
Question: What must be the appropriate SQL query for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This query is still valid, however other answers are better.
Fiddle is still valid though

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aac2/1/0

<strike>Here's about the best I could do for this time of night. Yes it's ugly (very, very ugly), but it gives the desired output. I really dislike that I had to use a union and an in, but it is late at night so I'm probably missing something. On that note, if this /is/ homework, you probably want to stay far far away from this solution. If it's not, there's a fiddle at the bottom to help other people help you</strike>

```
SELECT people.id,
   people.name,
   MAX(date_answered) AS date_answered
FROM people
LEFT OUTER JOIN answer_sheets ON answer_sheets.person_id = people.id
INNER JOIN surveys ON surveys.id = answer_sheets.survey_id
GROUP BY people.id,
     surveys.org_id HAVING surveys.org_id = 1
UNION
SELECT ALL people.id,
       people.name,
       NULL AS date_answered
FROM people
WHERE people.id NOT IN
    (SELECT person_id
     FROM answer_sheets
     INNER JOIN surveys ON answer_sheets.survey_id = surveys.id
     WHERE surveys.org_id = 1)
ORDER BY date_answered
```

Use one of the below solutions, left joining on a subquery is better. Fiddle is still valid though

If anyone wants to improve upon this, feel free to use this fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aac2/1/0

Answer (score 1):

This query is simpler:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    t.last_date_answered
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        a.person_id,
        MAX(a.date_answered) as last_date_answered
    FROM answer_sheets a
    INNER JOIN surveys s ON a.survey_id = s.id
    WHERE s.org_id = 1
    GROUP BY a.person_id) t ON p.id = t.person_id
ORDER BY t.last_date_answered;
```

The `UNION` is a powerful too but here the `LEFT JOIN` is less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  p.id, p.name, MAX(a.date_answered)
FROM
  people p
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM 
    answer_sheets a
  INNER JOIN
    surveys S ON a.survey_id = s.id
  WHERE S.orgid = 1) a
ON
  p.id = a.personID
GROUP BY
  p.id, p.name
ORDER BY MAX(date_answered) ASC
```

This is the most optimized answer. Credits to my friend Sheila Ruth Fausto.